# My naming convention for my android package is valid, and yet the manifest says that it isn't

Tags: java, android, manifest

I'm trying to create an app that sends and retrieves data from a database. when I try to build the project, an error pops-up that says that my package name is invalid. It keeps showing me this error

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Package 'com.example.rafaj.reservationtest;' from AndroidManifest.xml is not a valid Java package name as 'reservationtest;' is not a valid Java identifier.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwwoe.png)

Comment: It should be 'com.example.rafaj.reservationtest' instead of ''com.example.rafaj.reservationtest;'.
Remove the ';' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

remove ";" from your code

```
com.example.rafaj.reservationtest;
```

to 
`com.example.rafaj.reservationtest`